# MongoDB $sum Aggregate returns 0 in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the us-counties-2020.csv from https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data and I'm using this pipeline to aggregate the data in mongodb using nodejs.

```
const pipeline = [
{ $group: {
    _id: "$state",
    deaths: { $sum: "$deaths" },
    cases: { $sum: "$cases" },
 }},
 { $limit: 10 }
]
```

Expected: Returns the total for deaths and cases.

Actual: This returns 0s for deaths and cases when it should return the total sum for all deaths and cases respectively. Here is the console.log

```
{ _id: 'Rhode Island', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'Florida', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'South Carolina', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'Vermont', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'Missouri', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'Maine', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'District of Columbia', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'Tennessee', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'Ohio', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
{ _id: 'California', deaths: 0, cases: 0 }
```

How can I get the sum total of deaths and cases?

Comment: I used just the first portion of the file and your pipeline works fine on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pqWy1GzquRt).  Maybe `"deaths"` and `"cases"` are strings in your collection rather than integers?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I might be importing the data wrong - I just went to the data and downloaded it as a csv and imported the file into mongodb compass directly. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I just imported the same CSV with `compass` (most recent version).  In `compass`, after selecting the CSV file, a "mini-table" appears at the bottom where you can select which fields are imported and what types they should have.  For `"date"`, I selected `Date`. For `"fips"`, `"cases"`, and `"deaths"`, I selected `Int32`.  For `"county"` and `"state"`, I selected `String`.  After the import, you `"$group"` works fine in `compass`.

Comment: FYI, I usually use [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) for JSON/CSV/TSV file imports.  The `compass` import looks fine too.